# Android BLE - BT stack alarm errors

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-source

I'm trying to get basic Bluetooth LE connections working in my app, but I'm running into problems.  I have a couple of sensors that I can connect to just fine with the iOS version of this app, but I simply cannot connect to them with the Android version.  The only thing I seem to be able to connect to is a beacon I've set to configuration mode.

After checking my ADB logs again, I noticed that whenever it fails to connect to a device, there's always four calls to `bt_osi_alarm` and `bta_gattc_conn_cback`.  I'm wondering how to interpret this.

An unsuccessful connection attempt:

```
D/BluetoothGatt(17824): connect() - device: 00:17:E9:C0:86:14, auto: false
E/bt_osi_alarm(14357): reschedule_root_alarm alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns
...
E/bt_osi_alarm(14357): reschedule_root_alarm alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns
E/bt_osi_alarm(14357): reschedule_root_alarm alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns
E/bt_osi_alarm(14357): reschedule_root_alarm alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns
...
W/bt_btif (14357): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=3 connected=0 conn_id=3 reason=0x0002
W/bt_btif (14357): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0002
W/bt_btif (14357): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=5 connected=0 conn_id=5 reason=0x0002
W/bt_btif (14357): bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=6 connected=0 conn_id=6 reason=0x0002
D/BtGatt.GattService(14357): onConnected() - clientIf=6, connId=0, address=00:17:E9:C0:86:14
D/BluetoothGatt(17824): onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=6 device=00:17:E9:C0:86:14
I/mono-stdout(17824): BLEAdapter.OnConnectionStateChange()
I/mono-stdout(17824): Gatt disconnected!
```

A successful connection attempt to one of those beacons does not have these sets of four `bt_osi_alarm` and `bta_gattc_conn_cback` errors.  Preferably if someone knows the Android source well, hopefully they can tell me what's going on.  It's a long shot I know, but I'm kinda out of options.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same error in my code, could you please post some of your code or some more info about the Android Version, the library used (if so), etc? Thanks & good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information might help the community debug this issue for you. Please add the following to your original question:

- Make/Model/Revision of all BLE devices that you've tested and whether or not each one works
- Specific android device you have tested with
- The error your app gets and at what step it fails

  - Are you able to get a `BluetoothDevice`
  - Does it fail when calling `connectGatt()`
- Is your app written in java/android studio, or is this some kind of universal app that runs on both iOS and Android?

In my experience, *alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns*, isn't as serious as its error level suggests. On my nexus 7/marshmallow device, I see this message *constantly* while connected to a bluetooth device (serial profile, not BLE) so I don't think this is a bug.

I suggest checking up on the BLE device manufacturer to see if there are any firmware upgrades for them too.

#### More details on *alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns*

What's happening is some part of the android bt code is setting a very short timer. So short, that it expires before the app can measure it.

The error, *alarm expiration too close for posix timers, switching to guns*, was added to android source in a commit [081e4b67b44a5fd397c2d79a5566e11ae52d4aca](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/081e4b67b44a5fd397c2d79a5566e11ae52d4aca)

The commit message gives us more background on what is happening.

> Ensure alarms are called back when they expire in the past
>
> Turns out the posix timers we're dealing with aren't well behaved.
>
> If the timer is TIMER_ABSTIME the following is supposed to be true:
> "If the specified time has already passed, the function shall succeed
> and the expiration notification shall be made."
>
> But alas, this is not the case. If the expiration time happens to be
> in the past (e.g. very short timer which gets hit with a context
> switch before the timer can be set) the timer decides to disarm
> itself. This means no more callbacks happen, and no more alarms are
> processed ever.
>
> sadness.
>
> But thankfully, we can use timer_gettime to check the state of the
> timer after timer_settime. If timer_gettime tells us the timer is
> disarmed right after we armed it, we want to perform the alarm
> callback ourselves.
>
> Put all timer callbacks on the same thread (as would be the case in
> the underlying timer implementation already) and used a sempahore to
> signal when an alarm expires in the normal posix timer callback and
> also in the timer didn't set case.

The code also includes the following comments

> If next expiration was in the past (e.g. short timer that got context
> switched) then the timer might have diarmed itself. Detect this case
> and work around it by manually signalling the |alarm_expired|
> semaphore.
>
> It is possible that the timer was actually super short (a few
> milliseconds) and the timer expired normally before we called
> |timer_gettime|. Worst case, |alarm_expired| is signaled twice for
> that alarm. Nothing bad should happen in that case though since the
> callback dispatch function checks to make sure the timer at the head
> of the list actually expired.